# PHP web app works locally but not on Heroku -- Heroku can't find file path

Tags: php, heroku

So I've been working on a web app that scrapes tweets using Twitter's API and performs sentiment analysis on them.

It works locally, but when I post it to Heroku, the dynamic HTML of the display page won't display the processed tweets.

I've narrowed it down to my requiring twitteroauth before I make the API request, and my suspicion is confirmed in the log:

2020-10-05T14:53:23.642683+00:00 app[web.1]: [05-Oct-2020 14:53:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'twitteroauth/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /app/apirequest.php on line 4

**Here's the line of code that creates the error:**

`require_once ("twitteroauth/autoload.php");`

The thing is:

apirequest.php and the twitteroauth directory are siblings in the root directory of my project.

When I cd into twitteroauth on Heroku's console, it's empty, so autoload.php isn't there, though it obviously isn't empty on my local machine, or when I deploy it.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I have made sure that twitteroauth exists in my project in the same directory as apirequest.php prior to deploying it, and that twitteroauth contains all of its files as I originally obtained them. I haven't changed anything in the development/deployment process.

Comment: Then most likely you didnt copy everything you require up to the Heroku server

Comment: can you share the part of the code that generates the error?

Comment: @MarcelloPerri I just made that line more conspicuous.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I would be inclined to think that's the case, but I have everything prior to deploying it; the absence is only on Heroku.

Comment: php is telling you that the path  'twitteroauth/autoload.php' doesn't exist, you need to understand where autoload.php is and import it in a dynamic way, so if  apirequest.php is in the folder 'app', where is autoload.php? what folder is that file?

Comment: @MarcelloPerri apirequest.php and the twitteroauth folder are in the same directory at the same level--I mean that they're siblings--and autoload.php is in twitteroauth's root directory. So, autoload.php is one level down from apirequest.php and in a different folder. Is there a way that I can dynamically import autoload.php, i.e., not with require or include? The issue seems to be that autoload.php has disappeared when I deploy to Heroku--the entire contents of twitteroauth have.

Comment: have you tried with `require_once ("./twitteroauth/autoload.php");` ?